# Loss of data when using executeAsync in Cassandra

Tags: scala, cassandra, datastax-java-driver

Data insertion tests were performed using **executeAsync** in the datastax jdbc library, and some of them were lost.

The program is made of **scala** and I attach a code.

```
    val dataList = { 1 to 1000000 }
    Future.sequence(dataList.map(row => {
      val status = if (Math.round(Math.random() * 10) % 2 == 1) "on" else "off"
      val sensor = Sensor(id = row, status = status)

      writeToCassandra(sensor)
    }))

   def writeToCassandra(sensor: Sensor): Future[Unit] = {
     for {
       _ <- Future {
        session.executeAsync(s"insert into alpakka.sensor (id, status) values(${sensor.id}, '${sensor.status}')")
      }
    } yield ()
   }
```

Comment: Not sure about Scala, but if it was Java I would `listen` for the futures to complete after the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify, I'm assuming that you are referring to the [Cassandra Java driver](http://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/latest/) since the [Cassandra JDBC driver](https://docs.datastax.com/en/driver-matrix/docs/install-simba-drivers.html) is completely different.

You didn't provide sufficient details in your post, particularly evidence that data is "lost". This isn't possible in Cassandra so I'd be interested in seeing your evidence.

Instead, what I think is happening is that you are overloading your cluster because your code looks like something equivalent to a DDoS attack where you're firing off possibly thousands of random writes per second.

It is possible to overload your cluster using your code because the `commitlog` disks can only handle so much writes -- that's just physics. When it does get to the situation where nodes can no longer accept writes, they will drop those writes (known as "dropped mutations" in Cassandra) so those mutations never actually make it into the database.

Strictly speaking, dropped mutations is not equivalent to data loss because the writes were never accepted (acknowledged) by the replicas so you can't lose something that was never persisted to disk. Cheers!